# flutter windows app for accessing db installed locally

Tags: mysql, mongodb, windows, flutter, dart

Is there any method for accessing data from a local db installed in windows like mongo or mysql , for reading and writing data in flutter

Sample codes or methods for the implementation

Comment: you gonna need to use api and http request.

Comment: can i make this work within the same system the app and db installed

Comment: yeps you can do it, with it. api work as the middleman for other language or db

Comment: and also can i access it incase of offline , means in a case of no internet

Comment: ooooooh, i think you need to use `shared_preferences` package, check this out https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: my usecase is incase of no internet , i need to write some data to this locallly installed db , so am asking in this type of case is it possible to implement in windows with flutter app